# CSS shadow effect for a list of items

Tags: css, ionic2

I am using Ionic2 and have an `<ion-list>` of `items`. Currently they are just vanilla, but I would like to apply styling so that each item in the list had a gradual shadow effect as displayed in the first picture this example (however, instead of grey shading I would like to use a colour):

https://www.google.co.za/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.theartimes.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F03%2Fb558230ff6486bf2996aaebb181337e0.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.theartimes.com%2Fpage%2F17%2F%3Fp%3Donline-slot-machines&docid=NBkAfMRmbo-fjM&tbnid=-fRTtIx7JygAEM%3A&vet=1&w=600&h=1083&itg=1&bih=950&biw=1920&ved=0ahUKEwjc5L_00LHQAhXIBcAKHYdbCk84oAYQMwhCKD8wPw&iact=mrc&uact=8

My code is as follows:

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of personModels" (click)="itemTapped($event, item, true)">
      <ion-item class="item-search">
        <ion-avatar item-left><img [src]="item.avatar64 ? item.avatar64 : 'images/blank-profile-picture.png'"></ion-avatar>
        <ion-row >
          <ion-col><h2>{{item.person.firstName}}&nbsp;{{item.person.lastName}}</h2></ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row >
          <ion-col>more details</ion-col>
        </ion-row>
       </ion-item>

  </ion-list>
```

**UPADTE**

I added the following:

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of personModels" (click)="itemTapped($event, item, true)">
      <ion-item class="item-search">
...
    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>

.item-search {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -4px;
    background: black;
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin: -5px auto 0;
    z-index: 2;
    padding-left: 1px;
}
```

and this is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want a shadow, leave the box-shadow property alone for a bit, and try this out http://codepen.io/vividuaelsaphe/pen/xRRMxP

Basically:

```
.shadow {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -4px;
    background: black;
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin: -5px auto 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

So in your code it would be

```
<ion-col>
   <h2>{{item.person.firstName}}&nbsp;{{item.person.lastName}}</h2>
   <div class="shadow"><div> 
</ion-col>
```

Updated on codepen.

Comment: I think the close div tag is missing a /

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't work for me unfortunately. I think it's to do with the ionic tags. I will play around with it though. It's a good start

Comment: Oh, maybe you could try the same, but instead of `.shadow` just do `h2::after` with the same properties. That way you may not need an extra line.

Comment: I apologies, but for simplicity sake, I just showed one `row` in the `ion-item`. There is actually more than one, so I don't think that will work.  (I have updated above).

Comment: Ah, I see. Maybe you could post the code with some results, if possible?

Comment: I've just added a screen print of what I get above. Thanks